# Index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matrix

`FinalImg` is a 512x512 uint8 greyscale image. I'm trying to manually construct the histogram of the image. I used this exact same loop to construct a histogram beforehand and it is EXACTLY like what `imhist()` would produce, but for some reason it doesn't work this time and I get the error:

> Attempted to access imhistogramfinal(0,1); index must be a positive
>   integer or logical.
>
> Error in Project1 (line 77)

```
imhistogramfinal(FinalImg(i,j), 1)= imhistogramfinal(FinalImg(i,j), 1) + 1;""
imhistogramfinal = zeros(256, 1);

for i=1:512
    for j=1:512
       imhistogramfinal(FinalImg(i,j), 1)= imhistogramfinal(FinalImg(i,j), 1) + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: It says it must be a positive integer, and you're giving it 0.

Comment: Same error happens if I make the matrix ones(256, 1)